# How to check the condition if the json data (coming from backend) has a key value in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

In my angular application I Have fetched the data from the server and it is in json format like

```
jsondata = { 
    Id: 16531914, 
    EmailId: "abc@gmail.com" 
}
```

And my requirement is if the jsondata(coming from server ) has the Id then I have to navigate to the dashboard page else I have to go to the login page

Comment: That's not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use an if chek

```
if(jsondata.Id) return this.router.navigate([...other routes, jsondata.Id]) 
this.router.navigate(['/login'])
```

Answer (score 0):

When the JSON has been parsed into a JS object (via `JSON.parse` or Angular's `HttpClient` calling that internally) you can check if a field exists by comparing it against `null`:

```
if (jsondata.Id != null) {
  // navigate(etc)
}
```

Just doing `if (jsondata.Id)` won't work if the `id` field is `0` because `0` is a falsy value in JS. Doing a lose comparison to null (`!= null`) will capture both `undefined` and `null` but not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check, when the object is available or not

```
goto = (page) => {
  this.router.navigate([page]);
}

jsondata?.id ? this.goto(jsondata.id.toString()) : this.goto('login')
```